# Dropdown in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, html-select

```
ViewBag.Years = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1910, DateTime.Today.Year - 1910 + 1).Select(x =>
    new SelectListItem()
    {
         Text = x.ToString(),
         Value = x.ToString()
    }), "Value", "Text");
```

I am using this syntax to show the dropdown stating with 1910 year. But I need first value as blank as it is optional dropdown. How to attain that, any help would be appreciated

Edit: 
Renderer on the cshtml page

```
  <div class="col-@screenSize-4">
                        @Html.Label("Select Year")
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EventYear, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Years, new { @class = "form-control select-control", @data_placeholder = "Select one" })
 </div>
```

Comment: Show the syntax used to render it on the page, it could be that their is an overload provided for this case.

Comment: this can be done in the view with the Html.DropdownList() with a parameter called option **optionLabel**  eg `@Html.DropDownList("Years", null, "Select a Event Year", htmlAttributes: new { })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the list and then insert at position 0 the item you need. In this way it is the first item displayed at page load

```
List<SelectListItem> list = Enumerable.Range(1910, DateTime.Today.Year - 1910 + 1)
                            .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                            {
                               Text = x.ToString(),
                               Value = x.ToString()
                             }).ToList();
list.Insert(0, new SelectListItem{ Text = "(Select a year)", Value = "-1" });
ViewBag.Years = list;
```

Notice the special value assigned to the prompt item to let you undestand if some valid year has been selected

Comment: There is no inbuilt function "Insert" available. This code is not working

Comment: Modify your answer List<SelectListItem> list instead of var list and it works. Thanks modify declaration and I will mark you as the correct answer. I appreciate your help!